# Can't cut a simple box in half

Tags: modeling, vertices

I am trying to follow a tutorial to start building something using a cube but I can't even get past the first step, because even if I do exactly what they say, I don't end up with the same thing.

The steps I have followed

1. Select cube, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>1</kbd> to go to front view,
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>R</kbd>to put a line down the middle, click, have line.
3. Select all the vertices on that side, both used box select and then selected them all individually.

[image: as you can see here i have half the cube selected!]

I hit  <kbd>X</kbd>, delete vertices, and I am left with this:

[image]

Not half of a box, just one plane, no matter what I do! how am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 7):

You only need to delete the 4 vertices on the side.

[image]

You'll be left with an open half of a cube.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Currently, You're deleting all selected vertices, which includes the 4 around the center. If you want to delete only half of the cube, either go into *face* selection mode and delete, or in *vertex* selection, delete only the far left. Hope this helps!